# How to pass value from navigationController to TabBarController

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, swift2, ios9

I have a Login project. The first view controller is NavController and I need to pass user data to tabBarController where I have 3 NavigationControllers.

I tried this.

```
let openNewVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("mainNavID") as! UITabBarController
//openNewVC.token = token!
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(openNewVC, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the data from your first view Controller to view controllers which are embedded like as below in `UITabbarController`.

`UITabBarController -> UINavigationController -> UIViewController`

You need to traverse the `viewControllers` instance of `UITabBarController` and `UINavigationController` in order to get the instance of `UIViewController`. Once you will get the instance of 'UIViewController' which is embedded into `UITabbarController`, you can assign the data as required.

For Example

```
if let tabBarController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("mainNavID") as? UITabBarController {

    // Now you need to get View Controllers array from tabBarControllers which is UINavigationControllers
    if let navigationControllers = tabBarController.viewControllers as? [UINavigationController] {
    for navigationController in navigationControllers {
        //Now you need to get the viewControllers from navigationController stack,

         let viewControllers = navigationController.viewControllers

        //Now you can assing desired value in viewControllers, I am assuming you need to assign the same value in all viewControler
        for viewController in viewControllers {

        }
        }
    }
    }
```

The best way to pass the data in this kind of architecture using Singleton, Assume you created a class `Session` which member variable `token`.

```
class Session {

    //Singleton
    static let sharedInstance = Session()

    //Token which you assign and you can use through out application
    var token : String? = nil
}
```

Now, you can assign the token while pushing the `UITabbarController`.

```
 let openNewVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("mainNavID") as! UITabBarController
Session.sharedInstance.token = token    
//openNewVC.token = token!
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(openNewVC, animated: true)
```

Same token you can use within `UIViewController`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let token = Session.sharedInstance.token {
        //Now you have assigned token
    }
}
```

Comment: Singleton is the way I used 

Answer (score 1):

You could try to set the values to the `openNewVC` as you would set a normal property.

**Example:**

```
//set instance
var openNewVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("mainNavID") as! UITabBarController

// set properties
openNewVC.myFancyString = "Hello world!"

// set view controller active
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(openNewVC, animated: true)
```

Comment: Well what I want is. Pass data from mainVC to the VC located in TabBar Tree. Your code is exactly what I tried but failed cause I don't have custom class of TabBarCOntroller. With this code I can access destination VC but with no TabBar bottom.

Comment: Is it possible that you write your own TabBarVC?