# how can I move a data array between tab bar viewControllers when I have navigationControllers involved

Tags: swift, tabbarcontroller

I have a tab bar controller and 3 viewControllers connected to it and when I move data between the viewControllers I use the following code, which works perfect:

```
let secondTab = tabBarController?.viewControllers![1] as! ImageViewController
secondTab.imageArray = images
```

Now I added navigation to the second viewController with EDITOR->Embed In....so, there is now a navigationController between my ImageViewController and the tabBarController. How can I still get the data to the ImageViewController?

Comment: Have you seen this answer? Please check out. https://stackoverflow.com/a/33382923/4711785

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
if let nav = tabBarController?.viewControllers![1] as? UINavigationController {
 if let let secondTab = nav.topViewController as? ImageViewController
     secondTab.imageArray = images
  }
}
```